# Get CVPixelBuffer (camera frame along with ar models) in a performant manner

Tags: swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I need to get a `CVPixelBuffer` containing the camera frame along with the AR models that I've placed, at a rate of 30+ fps, preferably with low energy & CPU impact.

The capturedImage from the frame in `session(_:didUpdate:)` doesn't contain the AR models.

I've tried using `sceneView.snapshot()` to get `UIImage` which I then convert to `CVPixelBuffer`. This has a noticeably high energy impact.

Finally, I've also tried creating a `SCNRenderer` which I then use to get the `UIImage` via `snapshot(atTime:with:antialiasingMode:)` and later convert to `CVPixelBuffer`. This has a slightly lesser CPU and energy impact. But this only works for portrait mode, the generated `UIImage` is incorrect in landscape mode.

Is there a way to get `CVPixelBuffer` in a less CPU and energy intensive manner(at least when compared to the above)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own `CVPixelBuffer`, then get a `MTLTexture` from it and finally have `SCNRenderer` render into that texture. This won't involve the CPU cost of generating a `UIImage` from the snapshot API.

The key part here is to [use a `CVMetalTextureCache`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/1456754-cvmetaltexturecachecreatetexture) to obtain a Metal texture from a pixel buffer.

Comment: Could you share an example please?, I am stuck.